# Printing pages in Colour: hyperref and glossaries

Tags: hyperref, glossaries, printing

I am using the packages `hyperref` and `glossaries` and the the links are appearing in colour in the pdf. I have some colour in a few pages  which I want to print in colour. Now, the problem is that the links are also printing in colour.

When I use `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}` I get the following error.
`Option clash for package hyperref. \usepackage`.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{hidelinks}{hyperref}
```

before `\documentclass`. When `hyperref` is loaded later by whomever it will see the option.

Also `hidelinks` can be given later by `\hypersetup`:

```
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
```

Comment: The first option: put \PassOptionsToPackage{hidelinks}{hyperref}, did not work for me. However, the other option: \hypersetup{hidelinks} gave the intended result. Thank You :)

Comment: @Sooraj: If the first option does not work, then it is overwritten later by option `colorlinks` probably.